# After clicking submit button a card appears which shows the information i have submitted but the problem is that it is only displayed for few seconds

Tags: javascript

When i click on submit button the page gets submitted and a card appears which shows the information i have submitted but the problem is that it is only displayed for few seconds.

JavaScript Code

```
 <script>
      function closeDialog() {
        document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "none";
      }

      function openDialog() {
        var stdname = document.getElementById("txtName").value;

        document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("lblName").innerHTML = stdname;
        var personName = document.getElementById("registerName");
        var male = document.getElementById("optMale");
        var female = document.getElementById("optFemale");
        var bca = document.getElementById("optBca");
        var bsc = document.getElementById("optBsc");
        var mca = document.getElementById("optMca");
        var mtech = document.getElementById("optMtech");

        var gender = "";
        var qualification = "";

        if (male.checked) {
          gender = male.value;
        }

        if (female.checked) {
          gender = female.value;
        }

        if (bca.checked) {
          qualification = bca.value;
        }

        if (bsc.checked) {
          qualification = bsc.value;
        }
        if (mca.checked) {
          qualification = mca.value;
        }
        if (mtech.checked) {
          qualification = mtech.value;
        }

        document.getElementById("lblGender").innerHTML = gender;
        document.getElementById("lblQualification").innerHTML = qualification;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You're probably submitting a form which is redirecting the page, either have Javascript cancel the event when you listen for it, or don't use a form at all

Comment: Can you add the callers of these methods and some HTML contents?